# For loop in for loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I've got new project:
15 Draw a box with 5 rows so that once you write down your code to fillRect () function.
Each row corresponding to the number of the current line to be square (for example, in the third row of three squares).Why is not working :(

```
var c= document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext('2d');

var a= 10;
var b= 10;
var cw= 40;
var ch= 40;

for(i=1; i<= 5; i++){
  for(j=1; j<= 5; j++){

  c.fillStyle= '#fff947';
  c.fillRect(a,b,cw,ch);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you make same thing for 25 times ?

Comment: The code inside the two loops should be dependent on `i` and `j`.

Comment: It's the missing braces on the inner loop. Voting to close as a typographical error.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the curly braces inside your inner loop to make the code more readable.

Comment: @KevinAmiranoff That would change the meaning of the code. The question should _not_ be edited in this way.

Comment: @Xufox.. Alright, alright, I was just trying to be gentle.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what's the problem? Sorry... :(

Comment: Folks, the issue here was more than the missing braces around the inner loop. This question should not have been put on hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were missing the curly-braces around your inner loop's code and you weren't moving the x,y values when additional boxes need to be made on additional rows.

See comments inline for details:

```js
var can = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
can.style.width = "500px";
can.style.height = "500px";

var ctx = can.getContext('2d');

var x = 10;
var y = 10;
var w = 10;
var h = 10;

// Need to keep track of a horizontal indentation amount
// on rows where more than one box should be drawn.
var offsetX = 0;

for(i = 1; i < 6; i++){
  // Each new row should have the default indentaion
  offsetX = 10;
  
  // This loop needs to execute the amount of times that the 
  // outer loop has run (i.e. when i is 1, j should be 2
  // so that this loop will run once. This loop also needs
  // curly braces around its code.
  for(j = 1; j < i + 1; j++){
    ctx.fillStyle = '#fff947';
    ctx.strokeRect(x + offsetX, y, w, h);
    ctx.fillRect(x + offsetX, y, w, h);
    // On a given row, after making a box, increase the horizontal offset
    // by the width of one box.
    offsetX += w;
  }
  
  // After a row has been made, increase the vertical offset so that the
  // next boxes go below the previous ones. Change the y value to be the
  // old y value plus the height of a box plus 5 pixels just for a margin
  // between rows.
  y += (h + 5);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```